# Do I need a 'User Account' in order to retrieve data from a MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a page where anyone can open and press a button, and the information gets shown on the screen.

Do i need a guest account that is automatically called if the user doesn't have their own account, or can I have people press the button and information is called without having a guest account ?

Also will this present problems, if multiple people are on the page, and the same Guest account is used simultaneously ?

Comment: These questions are application-specific.  The answers will depend upon your requirements.

Comment: Well at at first I wount allow people to make accounts, so it would be just the Guest account and the Admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a db user for your application which will be used for executing SQL queries of non-authenticated users.

This should present no problems as long as guest users only read data from the database.

More on mysql transactions and internal locking:

[MySQL internal table locking methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html)

[innoDB transaction model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)

Comment: Is adding a guest account to the site the best way to approach this or is there an alternative ?

Comment: @Gerry it really depends on your requirements. Using a guest account is a common solution. Do you see any reasons why this wouldn't work for you? Do you have a specific use case in your application when using guest account might create potential risks?

Comment: No not really, since the Guest will only see select the data and not interact with it. I was just curious if there would be problems with multiple people online since all of them will be using the guest account. Is this the method that forums usually use (ie searching the forum) ?

Comment: @Gerry DB executes SQL queries one by one and, not really simultaneously (even when mysql receives both queries 'at the same time'). Furthermore, depending on your mysql engine, tables are either locked internally during sql query execution or the sql transactions could be used to make sure that data stays consistent while sql query executes.

Comment: Search on forums could be implemented in many different ways. Modern approaches use search engines, like Apache Lucene. They create efficient internal indexes of the db data and search within these indexes without sending any queries to the db. They do however update internal indexes on a regular basis and that's when they access the db. To access the db they use their own credentials.

Comment: Oh ok sounds very interesting, I'll look into those as well. Thanks for your help.